Cisco Packet Tracer and Ubuntu 24.04
I'm David Perlaza. Does anyone know if there is an updated version of Cisco Packet Tracer ? I can't install it on my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS environment, because this version of ubuntu doesn't handle some dependencies or packages like for example: libgl1-mesa-glx. Can anyone help me?

Please contact Cisco about their software
